# What are all the ways traffic to AWS can be blocked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've seen other questions where people are asking how to block traffic. I want this question to take a different approach.

Say you have an EC2 instance that you think should be receiving traffic at a specific address on a specific port, but it is not. What all do you check?

In other words, if you are have been given responsibility over an AWS account full of decisions you didn't make, what might someone else have done to cause you to lose your mind when this security group inbound rules fails you?

```
Type           Protocol    Port Range    Source
ALL Traffic    ALL         ALL           your.public.ip.addr/32
```

Comment: Internet Gateway object missing/deleted?  Subnet attached to wrong route table?  Default route for route table missing/deleted or not pointing to Internet Gateway object?  Instance with a public IP provisioned behind a NAT device?  ...or not your correct public IP?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are definitely onto something here. This is what I was looking for. I'm going to check out "Default route for route table missing/deleted or not pointing to Internet Gateway object?" I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all i could think of:

- AWS Level

  - VPC > Network ACL
  - Subnet > Network ACL
  - Load Balancer > Security Group
  - Instance > Security Group
- OS Level

  - Host firewall (iptables, windows firewall)
- Application Level

  - Web Application Firewall

Comment: I organized your bullets and added the VPC ACL. Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: This is also my understanding. However, I have a box that I still cannot reach in my primary VPC. I created an identical (Ubuntu 16.04) box on a new VPC and had no issues connecting to it.